# Database table is not JSON Serializable

Tags: python, json, postgresql, jupyter-notebook, typeerror

I'm setting up some python code in a Jupyter Notebook for a Machine Learning project using Ibm Watson and I keep getting a TypeError is not JSON serializable when I try to add datas from my Postgresql database table.

Here's the full output for clarity:

```
TypeError:                                           description
0   Lorem ipsum sjvh  hcx bftiyf,  hufcil, igfgvju...
1   Lorem ajjgvc wiufcfboitf iujcvbnb hjnkjc  ivjh...
2   Lorem aiv ibveikb jvk igvcib ok blnb v  hb b h...
3   Lorem jsvc smc cbd ciecdbbc d vd bcvdvbj obcvb...
4   Lorem jsvc smc cbd ciecdbbc d vd bcvdvbj obcvb...
5   Lorem jsvc smc cbd ciecdbbc d vd bcvdvbj obcvb...
6   Lorem jsvc smc cbd ciecdbbc d vd bcvdvbj obcvb...
7   Lorem jsvc smc cbd ciecdbbc d vd bcvdvbj obcvb...
8   Lorem jsvc smc cbd ciecdbbc d vd bcvdvbj obcvb...
9   Lorem jsvc smc cbd ciecdbbc d vd bcvdvbj obcvb...
10  Lorem sivbnogc hbiuygv bnjiuygv bmkjygv nmjhgv...  is not JSON serializable
```

And This is my python code that deploy the ML models to analyze theses datas which are random sentences as you can see, but will be product descriptions after testing:

```
from watson_developer_cloud import NaturalLanguageClassifierV1
import pandas as pd
import psycopg2


# Connecting to my database.
conn_string = 'host={} port={}  dbname={}  user={}  password={}'.format('159.***.20.***', 5432, 'searchdb', 'lcq09', 'Mys3cr3tPass')
conn_cbedce9523454e8e9fd3fb55d4c1a52e = psycopg2.connect(conn_string)
data_df_1 = pd.read_sql('SELECT description from public."search_product"', con=conn_cbedce2drf563454e8e9fd3fb8776fgh2e)

# Connecting to the ML model.
natural_language_classifier = NaturalLanguageClassifierV1(
    iam_apikey='TB97dFv8Dgug6rfi945F3***************'
)

# Apply the ML model to db datas
classes = natural_language_classifier.classify('9841d0z5a1-ncc-9076', data_df_1)
print(json.dumps(classes, indent=2)) # Pretty sure the error is happening here
```

How can I fix this?

**EDIT 1:**

I have tried to print this method: `print(data_df_1.to_json())`  to see if the format is in Json now and this is the output I'm getting:

`{"description":{"0":"Lorem ipsum sjvh  hcx bftiyf,  hufcil, igfgvjuoigv gvj ifcil ,ghn fgbcggtc   yfctgg h vgchbvju.","1":"Lorem ajjgvc wiufcfboitf iujcvbnb hjnkjc  ivjhn oikgjvn uhnhgv 09iuvhb  oiuvh boiuhb mkjhv mkiuhygv m,khbgv mkjhgv mkjhgv.","2":"Lorem aiv ibveikb jvk igvcib ok blnb v  hb b hb bnjb bhb bhn bn vf vbgfc vbgv nbhgv bb nb nbh nj mjhbv mkjhbv nmjhgbv nmkn","3":"Lorem jsvc smc cbd ciecdbbc d vd bcvdvbj obcvb vcibs j dvx","4":"Lorem jsvc smc cbd ciecdbbc d vd bcvdvbj obcvb vcibs j dvx","5":"Lorem jsvc smc cbd ciecdbbc d vd bcvdvbj obcvb vcibs j dvx"}}`

But I get this error now when I add this method: `classes = natural_language_classifier.classify('9841d0z5a1-ncc-9076', data_df_1.to_json())
print(json.dumps(classes, indent=2))` to the `classes`:

```
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-16-e72fac39b809> in <module>()
      1 classes = natural_language_classifier.classify('998520s521-nlc-1398', data_df_1.to_json())
----> 2 print(json.dumps(classes, indent=2))

/opt/conda/envs/DSX-Python35/lib/python3.5/json/__init__.py in dumps(obj, skipkeys, ensure_ascii, check_circular, allow_nan, cls, indent, separators, default, sort_keys, **kw)
    235         check_circular=check_circular, allow_nan=allow_nan, indent=indent,
    236         separators=separators, default=default, sort_keys=sort_keys,
--> 237         **kw).encode(obj)
    238 
    239 

/opt/conda/envs/DSX-Python35/lib/python3.5/json/encoder.py in encode(self, o)
    198         chunks = self.iterencode(o, _one_shot=True)
    199         if not isinstance(chunks, (list, tuple)):
--> 200             chunks = list(chunks)
    201         return ''.join(chunks)
    202 

/opt/conda/envs/DSX-Python35/lib/python3.5/json/encoder.py in _iterencode(o, _current_indent_level)
    434                     raise ValueError("Circular reference detected")
    435                 markers[markerid] = o
--> 436             o = _default(o)
    437             yield from _iterencode(o, _current_indent_level)
    438             if markers is not None:

/opt/conda/envs/DSX-Python35/lib/python3.5/json/encoder.py in default(self, o)
    177 
    178         """
--> 179         raise TypeError(repr(o) + " is not JSON serializable")
    180 
    181     def encode(self, o):

TypeError: <watson_developer_cloud.watson_service.DetailedResponse object at 0x7f64ee350240> is not JSON serializable
```

-

As you can see in the code, I want to deploy a machine learning text classifier to my description table in my database.

I am able to classify a single sentence with this code below but I want to classify the description table of my whole database:

`classes = natural_language_classifier.classify('998260x551-nlc-1018', 'How hot will it be today?')
print(json.dumps(classes.result, indent=2))`

And that is why I replaced the sentence with the dataframe `data_df_1`.

Comment: There is a `df.to_json()` method. [docs](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.to_json.html)

Comment: Thanks for your answer, where should I put this method? Could you include an example please?

Comment: I have tried to print this method: `print(data_df_1.to_json())` And the output is this:

Comment: @Iocq please [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/56259311/edit) your question rather than posting in the comments.

Comment: what are you trying to achieve with JSON ?

Comment: Question has been edited.

Comment: I reedited the question to include an example.

Answer (score 0):

You need to transform the table into a specific JSON format and use the `classify_collection()` method, as visible in the example in the [official documentation](https://cloud.ibm.com/apidocs/natural-language-classifier?code=python#classify-multiple-phrases)

```py
import json
from ibm_watson import NaturalLanguageClassifierV1

natural_language_classifier = NaturalLanguageClassifierV1(
    iam_apikey='{apikey}',
    url='{url}')

classes = natural_language_classifier.classify_collection('10D41B-nlc-1', [{'text':'How hot will it be today?'}, {'text':'Is it hot outside?'}]).get_result()
print(json.dumps(classes, indent=2))
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer @reportgunner! How can I replace the text values with the description datas that I have inside of my database tables named: `data_df_1` ?

Comment: tried to add this instead: [{'text':data_df_1.to_json()}] but I get this error: `WatsonApiException: Error: Not found, Code: 404 , Information: {'description': 'Classifier not found.'} , X-dp-watson-tran-id: gateway02-126492285 , X-global-transaction-id: ffea405d5ce6876fb574bfd` Do you know if my table name needs  to be 'text' instead of 'description'?